# Excessive Memory Spike On Postback Because Of Datatable

Tags: c#, .net, memory-management, memory-leaks, datatable

I basically have a listbox that has postcode areas i.e : AE,CW,GU etc etc.

The user selects this and then a postback occurs -  an sql statement is builts and a database query operation is performed and the results are returned to a datatable called tempdata.

So far so good. I then need to loop through this datatable and copy the records to my main viewstate datatable which is the datasource for google maps api.

```
  DataTable tempstore = GetData(querystring, "");

                        //check tempstore has rows otherwise add defaultcust as default otherwise map will be blank

                        if (tempstore.Rows.Count == 0)
                        {
                            tempstore = GetData("WHERE CUSTCODE=='CD344'", "");

                            infoalert.Visible = true;

                            infoalert.InnerHtml = "No Results Returned For Selection";
                        }

                        foreach (DataRow row in tempstore.Rows)
                        {

                            dtpc.ImportRow(row);
                            dtpc.AcceptChanges();

                        }

        //database command
 using (OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection(conString))
            {
                using (OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(query))
                {
                    using (OleDbDataAdapter sda = new OleDbDataAdapter())
                    {
                        cmd.Connection = con;

                        sda.SelectCommand = cmd;

                        sda.Fill(dt5);

                    }
                }
            }
```

So my main datatable can grow and grow as users add more postcodes. However when it gets to around 500 rows or so I get a huge memory spike only on postback and then it settles back down.My ram usage goes from 2gb to 3gb and if even more postcodes is selected it maxes the memory and crashes my pc.

If I remove the:

```
dtpc.Importrow(row);
```

the memory spike goes completely, obviously because the main datatable has no rows. I thought you only run into memory issues when you have thousands of rows?

Any help would be much appreciated.

thank you

Comment: Although this will probably not fix your memory leak you can get a performance boost if you place the dtpc.acceptchanges outside of the loop. Its cheaper to call it once after all rows are imported instead of doing it after every row.

Comment: thank you, this did not help the memory issue though :(

Comment: Format your code to the left

Answer (score 0):

Do you really need all the rows at once
A DataReader will access a single row at a time and keep you memory to a minimum
[DataReader class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.storage.streams.datareader.aspx)

If you need all you data at once create a class of strut for the data and hold it in a collection like a List.  DataTable is a heavy object.

And if you are measuring memory via Task Manager be aware it is not very accurate.

Comment: Yes I need all the rows at once as these are the user selection. The rows get plotted on google maps for the user to visually see. I dont see how 500 rows or so can cause such a huge spike in memory?

Comment: Create a class of strut to hold you data.  DatatTable is a heavy collection.

Comment: Ok, so at the moment I am using this : tempstoredt > maindt > repeater>googlemaps. How would I use your suggestion to bind to the repeater datasource

Comment: I was not asking for code. A simple and brief explanation would of been appreciated. But thanks for your advice - and also there are many sources online that say a datatable is fine unless you reach thousands of rows.

Answer (score 0):

First off, make sure you're wrapping any SQL execution in the appropriate "using" clauses. This is most likely the cause of your problem.

```
using (var command = new SqlCommand())
{
    // Some code here
}
```

Like Blam said, DataTable is too heavy for your purposes.

You can convert your data rows into class objects quite easily:

```
var datasourceList = new List<YourCustomObject>();

foreach (DataRow row in tempstore.Rows)
{
    var newMapsObject = new YourCustomObject
    {
        Value1 = row.Field<String>("Value1ColumnName"),
        Value2 = row.Field<String>("Value2ColumnName")
    };

    datasourceList.Add(newMapsObject);
}

viewStateList.AddRange(datasourceList);
```

To bind a custom collection to a data display (such as a repeater) you assign the list to the .DataSource property of said display, then call .DataBind(). This will work for most all ASP.NET data display objects.

```
repeater1.DataSource = viewStateList;
repeater1.DataBind();
```

Comment: Many thanks for your reply. Please see my original post, I have added the database using statements. I will try your suggestion and convert to class objects. Will I be able to add this to viewstate like I have done with the datatable like this: ViewState["dtpc"] = dtpc;
                          
                            Repeater1.DataSource = dtpc;
                            Repeater1.DataBind();

Comment: You should be able to, but I can't test it for you. And please take the time to align your posted code correctly - it's worth the extra few minutes to make it more readable, as opposed to copy+pasting it from Visual Studio.

Comment: I have put this in a list as you suggested and added custom objects to this list. The memory spike is better i.e I can add more postcodes before it starts to get bad. But it does still spike on postback, getting a spike of around 600mb and then it drops back down. Surely it shouldnt be using this much Ram?